# JMeter SocketException when uploading 1GB file

Tags: file-upload, jmeter, jvm

JMeter 5.4.1
OpenJDK 15.0.1

My test server is configured by default to allow a max 1073741824 byte file to be uploaded, a limit that is configurable.  My goal is to validate that the configured limit is respected.

When I configure it for 1048576 bytes and exceed that limit with my upload, the server sends the response:

```
"{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"|bd37f36b-4cd68e1b8b433669.","errors":{"":["Failed to read the request form. Multipart body length limit 1048576 exceeded."]}}"
```

When I configure it for 1073741824 bytes and exceed that limit with my upload, JMeter reports the following error:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implWrite(NioSocketImpl.java:420)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.write(NioSocketImpl.java:440)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$2.write(NioSocketImpl.java:826)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketOutputStream.write(Socket.java:1051)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.deliver(SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:342)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:1277)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.streamWrite(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:124)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.flushBuffer(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:136)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.write(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:167)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:113)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody.writeTo(FileBody.java:121)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl$ViewableFileBody.writeTo(HTTPHC4Impl.java:1513)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.AbstractMultipartForm.doWriteTo(AbstractMultipartForm.java:134)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.AbstractMultipartForm.writeTo(AbstractMultipartForm.java:157)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartFormEntity.writeTo(MultipartFormEntity.java:113)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:156)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.sendRequestEntity(CPoolProxy.java:152)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:238)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl$2.doSendRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:458)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:935)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:646)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:66)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1296)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1285)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:638)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

My JMeter.bat file has the heap set as follows:

```
set HEAP=-Xms1g -Xmx4g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
```

This looks to be similar to a post from last Oct, but there was no solution suggested/reported.
[SocketException after sending huge request via JMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64360159/socketexception-after-sending-huge-request-via-jmeter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Connection reset by peer` means that your server has reset the connection so you should rather look for the clue in your server logs.

The only thing I suggest to do on JMeter side is to consider switching to [HTTP Raw Request](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-http-raw-request-sampler-when-and-how-to-use-it) sampler, it has nice feature of [streaming the file directly to the server without loading it to memory first](http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/fileupload-test-with-JMeter-td4267154.html), I think you will find it extremely helpful when it comes to load testing with more than one virtual user. See [HTTP Raw Request for SOAP + MTOM](https://groups.google.com/g/jmeter-plugins/c/VDqXDNDCr6w) post on JMeter Plugins support forum for more details.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri.  It does indeed look to be the server according to some logs we found, though we are still looking into the specific cause.  Thanks very much for pointing me in the right direction!